# Proof of an identity of $n!$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, summation, factorial, finite-differences

I came up (numerically) with an identity concerning n! and I was wondering about a proof of it. Here it is:

\begin{align}
  \ n! &= \sum_{r=0}^{n} { \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r(k-r)^n  } \quad \forall n \in  \mathbb{Z}^+ \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{R} \\\\
\end{align}
(one line edit) I apologise for first accidentally writing $(-n)^n$ instead of $(-r)^n$, as I should have.

For simplicity, k can be set to 0 to yield:

\begin{align}
  \ n! &= \sum_{r=0}^{n} { \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r(-r)^n  } \\\\
\end{align}

I derived this equation based on that it seems to be the case that nth difference of a polynomial in the form \begin{align} y &= x^n \end{align} always ends up being n!. The origin of k is that it is the initial position from which I started taking the difference, but I left in as I thought it interesting that it cancels out completely. I know Calculus suggests it, but is there a way to prove it without calculus (my goal was to do it while keeping the difference in x constant, ie (x+d)^n - x^n, where d stays 1 preferrably)? So far my attempts yield nested sums.

I am not anything close to a mathematician, so I apologise if this is extremely trivial. Thank you.

Comment: That cannot be correct.  The sum $\sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}(-1)^r=0$ as it is the bionmial expansion of $(1+(-1))^n$.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, but does that not change when (-r)^n is used instead of (-n)^n, as I made in my corrective edit?

Comment: I once wrote down a very boring induction proof at http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/QEDMO6P4long.pdf (Theorem 1, equality (3)). The finite differences tactic that you mentioned is the standard way to prove this identity, though as you have expected it rests on some properties of finite differences which need to be proven. These are not too complicated, though: The main lemma is that if $P = P\left(X\right)$ is a polynomial (over the rational numbers) whose leading term is $aX^n$, then $P\left(X\right) - P\left(X-1\right)$ is a polynomial whose leading term is $naX^{n-1}$. You can apply this ...

Comment: ... inductively and then ask yourself which polynomials have leading term $n\left(n-1\right)\cdots 1 X^0$. There is also a combinatorial proof using the principle of inclusion and exclusion; can you find it? (I expect it to be in Stanley's EC1: http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ .)

Comment: The case $k=0$ follows from the fact that $S(n,n)=1$ where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind, since $S(n,n)=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-r}\binom{n}{r}r^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle P(x)=\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^r\binom{n}{r}(x-r)^n$; we want to show that $P(x)=n!$.

Since $\displaystyle P(x)=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}\bigg[\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-r)^jx^{n-j}\bigg]=\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\bigg[\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}r^j\bigg]x^{n-j}$,

it suffices to show that $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}r^j=0$ for $0\le j\le n-1$, $\;\;$and $\;\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n+r}\binom{n}{r}r^n=n!$

(as noted in WW1's answer).

---

Let $T(j,n)$ be the number of ways to distribute $j$ distinct balls into $n$ distinct boxes so that no box is empty,

so $T(j,n)=0$ if $j<n$ and $T(n,n)=n!$.

If we let S be the set of all ways to distribute the balls into the boxes, and

let $A_{i}$ be the set of distributions with box $i$ empty, for $1\le i\le n$,  we have

$T(j,n)=\lvert \overline{A_1}\cap\cdots\cap \overline{A_n}\rvert=\lvert S\rvert-\sum\lvert A_i\rvert+\sum\lvert A_i\cap A_j\rvert-\sum\lvert A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k\rvert+\cdots$

$\displaystyle\hspace{.47 in}=n^j-\binom{n}{1}(n-1)^j+\binom{n}{2}(n-2)^j-\binom{n}{3}(n-3)^j+\cdots+(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}(n-n)^j$

$\displaystyle\hspace{.47 in}=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n-r}\binom{n}{n-r}r^j=(-1)^n\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}r^j$.

Since $T(j,n)=0$ for $j<n$, $\;\;\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}r^j=0$ for $j<n$;

$\hspace{1.6 in}$and  $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n+r}\binom{n}{r}r^n=T(n,n)=n!$

Comment: Should it be $(-1)^{n+r}$ for the 2nd to last statement?

Comment: I am using the fact that $(-1)^{n-r}=(-1)^{n+r}$ in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

using the nested sums the general case can be reduced to the $k=0$ case with an interesting modification ...

$$ \begin{align}
 &\sum_{r=0}^{n} { \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r(k-r)^n  } \\
\\=&\sum_{r=0}^{n} { \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r \sum_{i=0}^{n} { \binom{n}{i} k^i(-r)^{n-i}  }}\\
\\=&\sum_{i=0}^{n} {\binom{n}{i} k^i  \sum_{r=0}^{n} { \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r (-r)^{n-i}  }}
\end{align}$$

for this result to be an identity in $k$, the second sum must vanish unless $i=0$

So the theorem can be proved by proving that

$$ \sum_{r=0}^{n} { \binom{n}{r} (-1)^r (-r)^{n-i}  }$$

vanishes if $1 \le i \le n$ and is equal to $n!$ if $i=0$