# Prove the identity $n! = \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k}(-1)^{n-k}k^n$ using a direct combinatorial argument

Tags: combinatorics

I am struggling to explain why the expressions on the left/right count the same thing. Can't use induction/generating-functions etc.

Comment: I do not understand the notation, especially the bounds in your sum. Can you explicitely write the first terms of the sum ?

Comment: @G.Fougeron Is it ok now? I've edited the title and I don't know if you commented before or after the edit.

Comment: probably after since I still don't understand the notatation

Comment: OK. Looks better to me.

Comment: I changed $t$ to $k$. It is more natural.

Comment: My best guess : This has to do with differentiation the polynomial $X^n$ $n$ times. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient in the section "Partial sums"

Comment: @aroz See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008394/is-this-identity-trivial-nn-n-sum-k-1n-1-1k1-binomnkn-kn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $n!$ is the number of bijection between $[n]=\{0,1,\ldots n\}$ and itself, which is also the number of surjection between $[n]$ and itself.

Now let $S$ denote the set of all functions from $[n]$ to $[n]$ and for $1\leq i\leq n$ let $A_i$ denote the set of functions from $[n]$ to $[n]$ which don't have $i$ in their image.

The number of surjections is then $n! = |\bigcap_{i=1}^n (S\setminus A_i)|$, because we can't miss any element in the image. By the inclusion/exclusion principle, we have

$$n! = |\bigcap_{i=1}^n (S\setminus A_i)| = |S| - \sum_{i=1}^n A_i + \sum_{1\leq i_1 < i_2 \leq n}^n (A_{i_1}A_{i_2}) -\ldots + (-1)^n(A_{i_1}A_{i_2}\ldots A_{i_n})$$

For any $1\leq i_1<i_2<\ldots i_k\leq n$ we have $|A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\ldots \cap A_{i_k}| = (n-k)^n$.

Thus the above becomes:
$$n! = |\bigcap_{i=1}^n (S\setminus A_i)| = |S| - \sum_{i=1}^n (n-1)^n + \sum_{1\leq i_1 < i_2 \leq n}^n (n-2)^n -\ldots + (-1)^n(n-n)^n \\
= \binom{n}{0} n^n - \binom{n}{1} (n-1)^n + \binom{n}{2} (n-2)^n -\ldots + (-1)^n\binom{n}{n}(n-n)^n\\
= \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(n-i)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(n-i)^n$$

By the substitution $k=n-i$ you get the desired formula.